# Ethernet II frames have broadcast MAC as destination (when connected to Raspberry PI access point running Hostapd)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables, raspberry-pi

I am having some strange (and oddly inconsistent) issues setting up a Raspberry Pi 3 AP, using a USB WiFi radio & directional antenna for an upstream connection to my residential internet wifi router. The rPi AP is on a different subnet than the upstream AP.

This is accomplished using iptables NAT forwarding, taking all traffic from the integrated wifi interface and forwarding it to the USB device:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o [USB Wifi Radio] -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i [USB Wifi Radio] -o [Integrated WiFi in AP mode] -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i [Integrated WiFi in AP mode] -o [USB Wifi Radio] -j ACCEPT
```

Strangely, one of my laptops (MBP) is able to connect to the internet using this setup, but the other (also MBP) does not get any response to its DNS queries or any other traffic being sent upstream.

After digging around with tcpdump and wireshark, I've discovered that all traffic originating from that machine has the broadcast MAC (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) in its Ethernet II frame destination field. I believe this is causing it to be dropped when it hits the iptables routing scheme because that is only matching on traffic whose destination is the [Integrated WiFi in AP mode] MAC.

Here's an example DNS query:

```
Frame 2: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits) on  interface en0, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_XX:XX:XX (28:cf:e9:XX:XX:XX), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.10.42.18, Dst: 8.8.8.8
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 58888, Dst Port: 53
```

The inconsistencies:

- This only happens on one of my two clients. The other laptop sends its frames out with the MAC address for [Integrated WiFi in AP mode] in the destination field, and its traffic is routed to the upstream network and out to the internet just fine.
- The "problem machine" also works just fine when connected directly to the upstream AP, and other APs I've tested. The frames have the appropriate MAC in the destination field. This leads me to believe it is indeed an issue with the RasPi configuration.
- I can see no differences between ARP exchanges when comparing the two clients connected to the RasPi.
- Also no differences between ARP exchanges when comparing the problem client connected to the RasPi and the same client connected to the upstream AP.
- DHCP handshakes also seem functionally identical along both lines of comparison.

I have had success creating a similar setup using the same upstream connection configuration, but forwarding the connection to the rPi's ethernet port (which was then connected to the WAN port on a Netgear WiFi router) instead of using the rPi itself as a hotspot.

I am pretty much at the limit of my current ability to understand what might be causing this, so let me know if it would be useful to post more info from the rPi's configuration (dhcpcd.conf, dnsmasq.conf, hostapd.conf, etc) or more captured traffic from either device.

## Edit:

**On the Mac experiencing issues**

ipconfig getpacket en0:

```
macbook:~ user$ ipconfig getpacket en0
op = BOOTREPLY
htype = 1
flags = 0
hlen = 6
hops = 0
xid = 0xcea51870
secs = 5
ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
yiaddr = 10.10.42.18
siaddr = 10.10.42.0
giaddr = 0.0.0.0
chaddr = 28:cf:e9:1c:e8:13
sname =
file =
options:
Options count is 10
dhcp_message_type (uint8): ACK 0x5
server_identifier (ip): 10.10.42.0
lease_time (uint32): 0xa8c0
renewal_t1_time_value (uint32): 0x5460
rebinding_t2_time_value (uint32): 0x93a8
subnet_mask (ip): 255.255.255.0
broadcast_address (ip): 10.10.42.255
router (ip_mult): {10.10.42.0}
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}
end (none):
```

ifconfig en0:

```
macbook:~ user$ ifconfig en0
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 28:cf:e9:1c:e8:13
inet 10.10.42.18 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.10.42.255
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect
status: active
```

arp -a:

```
macbook:~ user$ arp -an
? (10.10.42.0) at b8:27:eb:de:3d:b3 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.10.42.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

netstat -rnaf inet:

```
macbook:~ user$ netstat -rnaf inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use     Netif Expire
10.10.42/32        link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
10.10.42/24        link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
10.10.42.0         b8:27:eb:de:3d:b3  UHLWbIr         0        6     en0   1185
10.10.42.18/32     link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0      147     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1  1294604     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            1        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
```

### **On the Raspberry Pi**

cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.10.42.1,10.10.42.255,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=6,1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
domain-needed
server=1.1.1.1
bind-interfaces
bogus-priv
```

ip a:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827eb8b6896: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:8b:68:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:3d:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.42.0/24 brd 10.10.42.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6336:7760:8d5a:5552/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlx00c0ca84826b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:84:82:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.42/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx00c0ca84826b
       valid_lft 55299sec preferred_lft 41496sec
    inet6 fe80::2c0:caff:fe84:726b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Probably your dnsmasq.conf. And maybe the `ip a` output for the AP interface.

Comment: On the problem Mac, while it's connected to the rPi and exhibiting the problem, show us `ipconfig getpacket en0`, `ifconfig en0`, `arp -an`, and `netstat -rnaf inet`.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the response, I've edited the post to add that info.

Comment: Thanks @Spiff, I've added the output of those commands run on the Mac while the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because you are using the network ID of the subnet as the address of the AP, which will be used as the default gateway for the clients. I guess some could handle it but some not. (You are not supposed to do that anyway.)

Try assign `10.10.42.1/24` to `wlan0` *instead*. Also use `10.10.42.2,10.10.42.254` for `dhcp-range` instead. (You are not supposed to use `10.10.42.255/24` for a host either, as that's the broadcast address.)

Ref.: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addresses_ending_in_0_or_255

Comment: Nice catch. I know a Linux system must be manually tinkered with (by removing broadcast entries for .0 and .255 in the *local* routing table). Usually both sides have to.

Comment: Wow, well done @TomYan, that was it exactly. The fact that it was working for one of the clients totally threw me for a loop, I was convinced the basic setup was okay and that there was perhaps something not being communicated properly about it under particular circumstances. Seems I might need to revisit my networking 101 
Thanks again!